# Xamarin: No ClearCache method in Picasso

Tags: android, caching, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have installed a xamarin Picasso in my application, but wanted to clear the cached when the user logout my application. I can't find a ClearCache method which original Picasso library has one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you mean the memory or disk cache, so:

#### Disk cache:

Picasso defines its disk cache name as [(PICASSO_CACHE = "picasso-cache"](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/0230ba035e3c3aa7d0f31fa34359a66e62154b69/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Utils.java#L59)), so if you are not using a custom disk cache, you can delete the application's Picasso defined disk cache directly:

```
_picasso.Dispose(); // Done using Picasso
var cache = new File(BaseContext.ApplicationContext.CacheDir, "picasso-cache");
if (cache.Exists())
{
    cache.Delete();
}
// Recreate if needed, but Picasso Build() will recreate it if it does not exist
if (!cache.Exists())
{
    cache.Mkdirs();
}
```

#### If you are using your own `LruCache` or custom disk `Cache` implementation:

```
var cache = new File(BaseContext.ApplicationContext.CacheDir, "picasso-cache");
if (!cache.Exists())
    cache.Mkdirs();
_lruCache = new LruCache((int)Runtime.GetRuntime().MaxMemory() / 1024 * 8);
_diskLruCache = new DiskLruCache(cache, 10 * 1024 * 1024);
_picasso = new Picasso.Builder(BaseContext).MemoryCache(_lruCache).Downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(_OkHttp3Client)).IndicatorsEnabled(true).Build();
```

#### Clear memory:

```
_lruCache.Clear();
```

#### Clear disk cache via your custom disk cache implementation:

```
_diskLruCache.Delete(); // Assumes Android style DiskLruCache
```